# Как передать переменную вместо порядкового номера дочернего элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var postamountjs = postamount['0']; 


    $('.blogpost').css('list-style', 'none');
    $('.blogpost').addClass('none');
    $('.blogpost:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass('none');


});
```

```
$('.blogpost:nth-of-type(сюда нужно передать значение переменной postamountjs)').removeClass('none');
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.blogpost:nth-of-type('+ postamountjs +')').doStuff()`

Answer (score 0):

Так:     `$('.blogpost:nth-of-type('+postamountjs+')').removeClass('none');`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //var postamountjs = postamount['0']; 
  
    var postamountjs = 3; 


    $('.blogpost').css('list-style', 'none');
    $('.blogpost').addClass('none');
  
    $('.blogpost:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass('none');

  
    $('.blogpost:nth-of-type('+postamountjs+')').removeClass('none');

});
```

```css
.none {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="blogpost">1</li>
  <li class="blogpost">2</li>
  <li class="blogpost">3</li>
</ul>
```